# facebook sdk never returns to app in iOS5

Tags: ios, facebook

I am having a facebook share option in my project.I am developing it for iOS 5.The issue is when the control switches from my app to facebook app , it never comes back to my app. I have to manually switch to my app. This happens only when you first time install the facebook app and later it works fine that is , it returns to the app fine. But if you delete the facebook app and install it again, You will get the same problem. I have tried all the following methods.

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                                allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                           completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:(NSArray*)publishPermissions
                                defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                                   allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                              completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:
(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

and URL Types in target settings (info tab) as fbXXXXXX where XXXXXX is your fb app id

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all settings on Facebook are aligned:

[image]

Comment: After aligning it as you suggested, still the same issue.